# React native ref to a rendered class

Tags: class, react-native, render, ref

I am trying to create a trivial app: push a button and add an item to a list.

here is one try:

```js
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  } 

  onPressButton = () => {
    this.myRef.setState({data: [this.myRef.state.data, {key: 'test'} ]});
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <MsgList  ref={(comp) => {this.myRef = comp;}}/>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressButton}>
          <Text>press</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

MsgList

```js
class MsgList extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

this.Ref is a large circular structure but not a node so
[ref error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBS3s.png)

I tried ReactDOM.findDOMNode but get an error
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
[import error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7wdY.png)

I have tried MANY iterations.  My best guess is there is a better way to render MsgList.

Comment: There seems to be a part of MsgList render function missing, I'm guessing that's a FlatList? How do are sending the list to MsgList?

Answer (score 0):

### Recommend Solution

Use `state` in parent component to handle child `props` without `ref`.

**App.js**

```js
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  } 

  onPressButton = () => {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => ({ // Use setState for changing 
      data: prevState.data.concat({key: 'test'}),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MsgList  data={this.state.data} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressButton}>
          <Text>press</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

### Another Solution

The `setNativeProps` can be the way you want.

**App.js**

```
onPressButton = () => {
  this.myRef.setNativeProps({ // Change ref's props directly
    data: {key: 'test'}
  });
},
```

**MsgList class**

```
class MsgList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.props.data} // Get data from props. 
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But it can be a performance bottleneck.

> Use setNativeProps when frequent re-rendering creates a performance bottleneck
>
> Direct manipulation will not be a tool that you reach for frequently; you will typically only be using it for creating continuous animations to avoid the overhead of rendering the component hierarchy and reconciling many views. setNativeProps is imperative and stores state in the native layer (DOM, UIView, etc.) and not within your React components, which makes your code more difficult to reason about. Before you use it, try to solve your problem with setState and shouldComponentUpdate.

[Official](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation)

## Why?

The `state` should be managed by component self. That is why `this.ref.state` is null you tried before. Thus, you could transfer props to child from parent through `setState` if the value is dynamic. 
And `state` Updates may be asynchronous. That is why I use `prevState` in `setState`. [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) is a great solution

Comment: @user3741628 That is exactly same concept with my recommend.

Answer (score 0):

based on input I [lifted the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

         this.state = {
            data: [{key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},]
         }
    }


    onPressButton = () => {
        this.setState({data: this.state.data.concat( {key: 'test'} )});
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <MsgList data={this.state.data}  />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressButton}>
                <Text>press</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

 class MsgList extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
            data={this.props.data}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It will be better to use `prevState` in `setState` for preventing fail concat as my recommend answer.